# Firefox password manager dead after transfer from Windows to Linux

Tags: linux, firefox, passwords

I copied my Firefox profile from a Windows installation to Linux (Fedora Workstation to be specific). My open tabs, extensions, saved forms survived the migration perfectly but the password manager did not:

1. Instead of my saved logins it displays an empty list.
2. It does it allow me to save new logins - the "save password" popup works as usual, but nothing is stored.

The `logins.json` and `key4.db` files are present, permissions are 644. I see the names of the old (before transfer) saved sites in `logins.json`. However, the files still have timestamps and sizes they had before transfer.

Any suggestions?

**UPD:** Tried file access monitoring with `inotifywatch`:

```
[zorath@localhost 1]$  inotifywatch /home/zorath/.mozilla/firefox/msl/key4.db /home/zorath/.mozilla/firefox/msl/logins.json
Establishing watches...
Finished establishing watches, now collecting statistics.
^Ctotal  access  close_nowrite  open  filename
3      1       1              1     /home/zorath/.mozilla/firefox/msl/logins.json
[zorath@localhost 1]$
```

The conclusion is that Firefox sees the file(s) and is able to read them but does not want to.

Comment: Are you sure Firefox is actually using the profile you migrated?  In other words, does the password manager, show your existing passwords?

Comment: Yes, Firefox is using this profile. Tabs, extensions, saved forms - everything is there; only the passwords are dead. Password manager shows an empty list of saved logins. (Guess I should add this detail to the question. My bad.)

Comment: You have verified that the permissions on the file are correct?  In other words you have created a new Firefox profile, saved a random password, then verified the permissions are identical to that of the current file?

Comment: This is in fact a great idea. Will give it a try now.

Comment: Okay, saving logins worked in a new profile. Newly created `logins.json` and `key4.db` have permissions 600, which is more restrictive than the 644 the faulty ones have. I changed permissions for the faulty files to 600 just to be certain, but it did not help.

Answer (score 1):

In your profile, there will be a file named pkcs11.txt that contains the path to the database (on the old Windows machine).
Close Firefox, rename this file to pkcs11.txt.bak then open Firefox again.
A new pkcs11.txt will be auto-generated with the correct paths and restore the password manager and all it's previously saved logins.

the same tip is also good to restore the password manager in Thunderbird after a Windows to Linux transfer.

Comment: I have confirmed that modification of the path restored access to the saved logins